# Recursively change file extensions in Bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sh

I want to recursively iterate through a directory and change the extension of all files of a certain extension, say `.t1` to `.t2`. What is the bash command for doing this?

Comment: imho this is not a duplicate question - the other question is not recursive

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/35922/how-do-i-change-extension-of-multiple-files-recursively-from-the-command-line

Comment: @AmalAntony : If you don't have `rename`, write a shell script, which renames a single file (trivial to do in your simple case), and then use `find` to apply this script to all files with the offending extension.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Use:

```bash
find . -name "*.t1" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.t1}".t2' - '{}' +
```

If you have `rename` available then use **one** of these:

```bash
find . -name '*.t1' -exec rename .t1 .t2 {} +
```

```bash
find . -name "*.t1" -exec rename 's/\.t1$/.t2/' '{}' +
```

---

For a single file use the `+` delimiter and for renaming all files at once use the `;` delimiter.
Example:
For a single file

```bash
find . -name "*.t1" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.t1}".t2' - '{}' +
```

And for all files in the scope of the find command:

```bash
find . -name "*.t1" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.t1}".t2' - '{}' \;
```

Comment: `find . -name '*.t1' -exec rename .t1 .t2 {} +`

Comment: (My version of `rename` doesn't allow the sed style substitution expression. Gotta love Linux. I used to have to install TotalCommander for Windows to do stuff like this.)

Comment: Please use a parameter expansion instead of an ugly `sed`!

Comment: If you have the extensions in variables, you cannot use single quotes here.  `find . -name "*.$ext1" -exec bash -c "mv \"\$1\" \"\$(sed 's/\\.$ext1\$/.$ext2/' <<< \"\$1\")\"" - {} \;` should work instead, though this is much more involved than I would like it to be.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering what the `"${1%.t1}".t2` part does, like I did: It uses bash string manipulation to do the following: 1/ Take the first positional parameter `$1` and truncate the `.t1` string literal from its end (percentage sign `%` operator). 2/ Append the `.t2` string literal to the result.

Comment: The rename didn't work for me in OSX, but the bash version is awesome b/c I just added 'git' in front of mv and now git is happy :-D

Comment: prefer to user `find  . -type f -name '*.t1'` to avoid folders

Comment: works like a charm! Install "rename" by `sudo apt install rename`

Comment: Another form would be `mv "$1" "${1/.t1/.t2}"` this uses find and replace, but your filename need to have only one ".t1".

Comment: @AaronBlenkush In Windows I would use PowerShell for this: `gci -r *.t1 | foreach { $_ -replace ".t1", ".t2" }` these commands will print the filenames renamed.

Comment: On MacOS it only renames the first matched file

Comment: Delimiter argument should be `;` instead of `+` if renaming all at once is required like this `find . -name "*.t1" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.t1}".t2' - '{}' \;`. Otherwise with the `+` only one file will be renamed at a time. [Ref](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/find-exec-command)

Answer (score 60):

None of the suggested solutions worked for me on a fresh install of debian 11.
This should work on any Posix/MacOS

```
find ./ -depth -name "*.t1" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.t1}.t2"' _ {} \;
```

All credits to:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/35922/how-do-i-change-extension-of-multiple-files-recursively-from-the-command-line

Comment: Thanks for this.  The rename stuff in the selected answer doesn't work on Ubuntu 20

Comment: This is the only one worked for me. None of the accepted answer methods worked.  I am on Ubuntu so probably a Debian/CentOs whatever thing. cheers

Comment: What? Debian 14? Are you from the future?

Comment: ty, this worked great. It would be great to include a short explanation for some of the pieces of the command that aren't intuitive to beginners (ex. `_ {} \;`)

Answer (score 17):

If your version of `bash` supports the `globstar` option (version 4 or later):

```sh
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.t1; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.t1}.t2"
done
```

Answer (score 11):

I would do this way in bash :

```
for i in $(ls *.t1); 
do
    mv "$i" "${i%.t1}.t2" 
done
```

EDIT : 
my mistake : it's not recursive, here is my way for recursive changing filename :

```
for i in $(find `pwd` -name "*.t1"); 
do 
    mv "$i" "${i%.t1}.t2"
done
```

Comment: [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and see the same page for why your `find` syntax is bad. Also, make sure you [quote your variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting)

Answer (score 5):

Or you can simply install the [`mmv`](http://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html) command and do:

```
mmv '*.t1' '#1.t2'
```

Here `#1` is the first glob part i.e. the `*` in `*.t1` .

Or in pure bash stuff, a simple way would be:

```
for f in *.t1; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.t1}.t2"
done
```

(i.e.: `for` can list files without the help of an external command such as `ls` or `find`)

HTH

Comment: I assume the OP's use of "recursively" refers to renaming files in subdirectories of the directory as well.

Comment: it's the first glob part i.e. the `*` in `*.t1`

Answer (score 1):

My lazy copy-pasting of one of these solutions didn't work, but I already had [`fd-find`](https://crates.io/crates/fd-find) installed, so I used that:

```
fd --extension t1 --exec mv {} {.}.t2
```

From `fd`'s manpage, when executing a command (using `--exec`):

```
          The following placeholders are substituted by a
          path derived from the current search result:

          {}     path
          {/}    basename
          {//}   parent directory
          {.}    path without file extension
          {/.}   basename without file extension
```