# How to rename a batch of files with webstorm 10

Tags: webstorm

I want to change in a project from javascript to typescript.
Therefore i want to change the extensions of all files from *.js to *.ts recursively.
How do i accomplish it with webstorm?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no way to rename multiple files in the project in WebStorm, unfortunately.
You can vote for the related [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108264) on JetBrains issue tracker.

Answer (score 9):

Do it outside of Webstorm on linux (or Windows git bash) with ..

```
cd my-folder

find . -name "*.t1" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.t1}".t2' - '{}' \;
```

courtesy of [Recursively change file extensions in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985492/recursively-change-file-extensions-in-bash#answer-21985531)

This works recursively, make sure you cd to the correct folder first (typically your project root folder).

Comment: If you want to keep all the `git` history then add `git` before the `mv`, like that `find . -name "*.t1" -exec bash -c 'git mv "$1" "${1%.t1}".t2' - '{}' \;
`

Answer (score 1):

There is this awesome plugin for webstorm and jetbrains IDES:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17063-regex-rename-files
[image]