# How to rename files in VS Code in bulk?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to search for ALL .txt files in a project and automatically replace/rename them to .js?

E.g user.txt to user.js

It seems I can't search for a **file format** in VS Code.
If you know how, please share!

Comment: Why do you need to do this using vscode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursively change file extensions in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985492/recursively-change-file-extensions-in-bash)

Comment: Try using powershell from terminal

Comment: extension called batch rename. but it won't update symbols. so... yeah.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of:

- Filtering the EXPLORER panel to just show `.txt` files

  - See ["Filtering the document tree"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_filtering-the-document-tree) section of the VS Code docs
  - See related Stack Overflow post: ["Filter files shown in Visual Studio Code"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31639563/2745495)
- Installing and using the [Batch Rename](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JannisX11.batch-rename-extension) extension

For example, given these files/folders:

[image: VS Code screenshot of initial file/folders]

Steps:

1. Start by clicking on the EXPLORER panel and filtering to just display `.txt` files

   [image: VS Code screenshot with filtered .txt files]
2. Select/highlight all the files, then right-click on any selected file, then select "Batch Rename"

   [image: VS Code screenshot of context menu with "Batch Rename" highlighted]
3. That would open a text file **".Batch Rename.txt"** with all the selected files

   [image: VS Code screenshot with Batch Rename.txt]
4. Do a regular find-and-replace to change `.txt` to `.js`

   [image: VS Code screenshot with Batch Rename.txt with .txt changed to .js]
5. Note that the **".Batch Rename.txt"** is unsaved. It's like a preview of what the changes would look like
6. Save **".Batch Rename.txt"** and it will automatically close
7. The EXPLORER panel should now be empty since it's filtered on `.txt`

   [image: VS Code screenshot with empty EXPLORER panel]
8. Remove the filter and the files should now be renamed

   [image: VS Code screenshot with .txt changed to .js]

Answer (score 2):

You could just do it in the terminal.

```
mv *.txt *.js
```

Comment: This does not rename the files inside sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to do this in a terminal recursively.

```sh
find . -iname "*.txt" -exec rename .txt .js '{}' \;
```

refer [Find multiple files and rename them in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541582/find-multiple-files-and-rename-them-in-linux)

`mv` works if you want to just do it in a folder itself.

Comment: doesn't work on osx

Comment: Did not work for me on Windows, says it can't find rename command

Answer (score -1):

Old question, I know, but for you or anyone else coming in, if you're okay with using a non-VS Code solution, there's a GUI Windows tool called [RegexRenamer](http://regexrenamer.sourceforge.net/) that is so well-named, you already know what it does.

It gives you a preview of what the renamed files will look like, and has options to rename everything in subfolders or only the current folder, ignore/include file extensions in the search, and apply the rename only to folders/files or both.

What do you think?

Comment: Couldn't install this one, it gives me an error during installation wizard.

Comment: @ArturBalestro and what does that error say? (I've only used this program on Windows, btw)

Comment: @D@ddy7860  The error is: Error downloading file: File Not found (404), when trying to install .NET 2.0

Comment: @ArturBalestro So I'm assuming the step-by-step process you followed to reach this point is
1. Downloading the regexrenamer installer from the official linked website
2. Running the installer on Windows
3. Seeing this error pop up during the installation?

Or did you do something else?

Comment: @D@ddy7860 The steps you mentioned is exactly what I did. The moment I start the installation, the error mentioned above pops up

Comment: @ArturBalestro well I have no idea how that's happening then. Have you tried looking for & using an older installer, or a portable version?

Comment: I did, but I couldn't make it work anyway. I've since given up on this and done the manual way.